# Converting System.Net.Configuration.DefaultProxySection to WebRequest.DefaultWebProxy

Tags: c#, dynamic, proxy, config

In my Web and Desktop application (which shares the same common library) the proxy is configurable. So when the user disables the proxy, `System.Net.WebRequest.DefaultWebProxy = null;` is set, effectively disabling the proxy. But when the user enables the proxy, the application needs to re-instate the proxy configurations from web.config or app.config (based on the application type).

So far I can read the default proxy configuration from config file as shown below,

```
var defaultProxy = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.GetSection("system.net/defaultProxy") as System.Net.Configuration.DefaultProxySection;
```

Is there a direct way to convert `DefaultProxySection` to `System.Net.WebRequest.DefaultWebProxy` without picking each and every configuration from the `defaultProxy` variable and assigning it  to a new DefaultWebProxy variable and assigning it?

Answer (score 0):

This functionality is implemented in the class [`DefaultProxySectionInternal`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/net/System/Net/Configuration/DefaultProxySection.cs,2aebd6dc78058e53,references) which is internal to the System assembly and cannot be used by your code.

My suggestion would be to store a reference to `System.Net.WebRequest.DefaultWebProxy` before setting it the first time and then reusing this when the proxy settings from the configuration should be used.